# Anime/cartoon with a man whose shirt rips off and eyes glow red when he activates two metal objects

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, animation

I've been searching for this anime/cartoon for about 15 years. My local VHS library had this anime (I guess) movie. I can only remember this one scene.

On a hill, near a dojo-like house with those thin wooden doors, a man parks his car. I think there was a grave there or some type of memorial stone. An old man comes out to greet him. He opens his trunk to reveal all kinds of weapons. But he doesn't take all the huge guns or bombs. He takes a small silver suitcase.

Inside, there are two metal objects. He takes them and then, when he activates them (later I think), he burns in red energy, like Goku, let's say. And his shirt rips off and his eyes glow red, I think. And the old man inside the house transforms into a demon or a monster, ripping his skin off. And many more similar creatures attack this main character, but he kills them all in a very gory fashion.

There was maybe some kind of green metal pyramid on the VHS cover art. Maybe only the cover was green. I also remember a lady on the cover. They were maybe something like FBI agents, looking for some sort of artifact (maybe that weapon that he uses... I can't remember anymore).